# NullPointerException when testing controller in Play 2.6

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, nullpointerexception, play-reactivemongo

I'm working on a Scala Play 2.6 application that uses ReactiveMongo. I've followed the example of [HomeControllerSpec.scala](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-seed.g8/blob/2.6.x/src/main/g8/test/controllers/HomeControllerSpec.scala) of the default Play 2.6 installation (play-scala-seed.g8) to test my ProjectController by creating a new instance of it but I am getting a `NullPointerException`.

Here's my controller:

```
class ProjectController @Inject()(
      cc: ControllerComponents,
      val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi
  )(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractController(cc) with I18nSupport {

  def collection: Future[JSONCollection] = reactiveMongoApi.database.map(
    _.collection[JSONCollection]("project")
  )

  def listProjects: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request =>
    val futureProjectsList: Future[List[Project]] = collection.flatMap(
      _.find(Json.obj())
      .projection(Json.obj())
      .cursor[Project]()
      .collect[List](-1, Cursor.FailOnError[List[Project]]())
    )

    for {
      projectsList <- futureProjectsList
    } yield {
      Ok(views.html.project.list(projectsList))
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my test:

```
class ProjectControllerSpec extends PlaySpec
  with GuiceOneAppPerTest
  with Injecting
  with MockitoSugar {

  val mockedReactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi = mock[ReactiveMongoApi]
  val mockedExecutionContext: ExecutionContext = mock[ExecutionContext]

  "ProjectController GET" should {
    "render the 'List of Projects' page from a new instance of controller" in {
      val controller: ProjectController = new ProjectController(
                                                      stubControllerComponents(),
                                                      mockedReactiveMongoApi
                                                    )(mockedExecutionContext) {
        override def collection: Future[JSONCollection] = mock[Future[JSONCollection]]
      }
      val result = controller.listProjects().apply(FakeRequest(GET, "/projects"))

      status(result) mustBe OK
      contentType(result) mustBe Some("text/html")
      contentAsString(result) must include ("Projects")
    }
  }
}
```

But when I run the test I get:

```
[info]   java.lang.NullPointerException:
[info]   at controllers.ProjectController.$anonfun$listOfProjects$1(ProjectController.scala:51)
[info]   at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilderImpl.invokeBlock(Action.scala:482)
[info]   at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilderImpl.invokeBlock(Action.scala:480)
[info]   at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$2.apply(Action.scala:419)
[info]   at controllers.ProjectControllerSpec.$anonfun$new$2(ProjectControllerSpec.scala:40)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf$(OutcomeOf.scala:83)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
```

I also run 2 other tests for this controllers and they pass (render page from the app by injecting the controller, rendering from the router). So how can I get this test to pass? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `NullPointerException` comes from the use of the mock objects that have no defined behavior. So when the execution reaches `reactiveMongoApi.database` this will cause the exception.

This [github project](https://github.com/themillhousegroup/play2-reactivemongo-mocks) introduced a way of mocking the reactive mongo api but it's not really maintained anymore.

You can also check [acolyte](http://acolyte.eu.org/reactive-mongo/) that allows you to mock the mongo connection.

By the way, you should not use mocks for the `ExecutionContext`, otherwise your `Future`s won't work